# Setting value of CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm developing a function on my website where a user should be able to edit his or hers own topic using ckeditor 5 and a textarea. The textarea is placed inside a modal. However, when I try to prefill the textarea when a user pushes a button, nothing goes inside the textarea. I have tried the following:

```
var editor;
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#edit-reply-modal'))
  .then(editor => {
    editor = editor;
  })
$(".toggle-edit-modal").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  editor.setData("<p>Testing</p>"));
$("#edit-reply-modal").html("<p>Testing</p>");
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a live example? Cause calling `editor.setData()` is the right way to set the editor's data.

Comment: Note: editor's data !=== textarea. Editor lives next to the textarea which it replaces. It takes the content from it on start and set it back on form save or when it's destroyed.

Answer (score 6):

I see you have one ')' more than needed `editor.data.set("<p>Testing</p>"));`

If you still can't set data, than try to set data like this :

```
 editor.data.set("<p>Testing</p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Html :

```
   <!-- The editable element in the editor's DOM structure. -->
    <div class="... ck-editor__editable ..." contenteditable="true">
        <!-- Editable content. -->
    </div>
```

vanilla Javascript :

```
// A reference to the editor editable element in the DOM.
const domEditableElement = document.querySelector( '.ck-editor__editable' );

// Get the editor instance from the editable element.
const editorInstance = domEditableElement.ckeditorInstance;

// Use the editor instance API.
editorInstance.setData( '<p>Hello world!<p>' );
```

Docs : https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html

Comment: You saved my day man! thnx!

Answer (score 1):

HTML Code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/24.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="edit-reply-modal"><p>Old Data</p></textarea>
<button id="toggle-edit-modal">Fill New Data</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code:

```
let YourEditor;
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#edit-reply-modal'))
  .then(editor => {
    window.editor = editor;
    YourEditor = editor;
  })

$('#toggle-edit-modal').on('click', function() {
  YourEditor.setData('<p>This is the new Data!</p>');
})



let YourEditor;
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#edit-reply-modal'))
  .then(editor => {
    window.editor = editor;
    YourEditor = editor;
  })

$('#toggle-edit-modal').on('click', function() {
  YourEditor.setData('<p>This is the new Data!</p>');
})
button{
  margin-top:20px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background: #00F;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/24.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="edit-reply-modal"><p>Old Data</p></textarea>
<button id="toggle-edit-modal">Fill New Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html#manually-retrieving-the-data) unlike ckeditor4 there is not any `CKEDITOR.instances`, so if you want to update your editor content, you can create a global instance of yor editor and then use `setData()` in order to update content by `ajax`.

Sample Code:

```
    let myEditor;

    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#menuContent'), {
            language: {
                // The UI will be English.
                ui: 'fa',

                // But the content will be edited in Arabic.
                content: 'fa'
            },
            placeholder: 'متن منو را وارد نمایید...'
        })
        .then(editor => {
            window.editor = editor;
            myEditor = editor;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err.stack);
        });

    function ShowMenuDetails(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("MenuDetails", "Admin")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#menuTitle").val(data.MenuTitle);
                $("#order").val(data.MenuOrder);

                myEditor.setData(data.MenuContent);

                $("#myModal").modal();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function (content) { alert(content); },
                500: function (content) { alert(content); }
            }
        });
    }
```